# Can I make a snappables snapchat game with lens studio?

Tags: snapchat

I have searched through Snap Chats website and have not found info regarding publishing Snappable games.

Can I create and publish a Snappable game with Snap Chat Lens Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I saw several Snapchat team people who say no, it's not available.

For the moment we can use the Highscore template, or play with local Storage to create game experience with Text (like quiz) or 3d models.